# Корректно настроить сайт

Tags: .htaccess

Проблема вот в чем. Есть сайт, скажем www.site.ru, на котором все отлично работает, но если зайти, набрав адрес qwerty.site.ru или qwert.y.site.ru то отображается полный алиас основного сайта. Как сделать так (через .htaccess или настройку зоны), чтобы по адресам qwerty.site.ru  и qwert.y.site.ru ничего не отображалось, т.к. этих поддоменов в принципе не существует?

На сервере стоит панель ISPManager Lite.

Comment: попробуй использовать простой редирект с ***.site.ru** на **site.ru** и все

Comment: Это же надо спрашивать у Вашего "хостера": "Как настроить DNS моего сайта?"

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, о таких вопросах надо спрашивать хостера - это их обязанность. Через панель ISPManager нельзя удалить поддомены, но если у вас есть доступ к серверу, то можно воспользоваться скриптом для удаления домена или поддомена с сохранением алиаса сайта.
[Вот ссылка на плагин](http://usings.ru/2010/06/25/isp-plugin-wwwdomain-sd/) и инструкцию к нему